# Ubuntu - python2 and python3 coexist - installing library

Tags: ubuntu, python-3.x, python-2.x, coexistence

I have a silly problem. I wrote a simple application in Python3. I was testing it on my local machine with Windows and Python3 only so when I installed psutil everything worked just fine. However when I've sent it to the target system with Ubuntu problems started. There two instances of python on this machine: 2.7 and 3.2.3. I tried to install psutil by `sudo apt-get install python-psutil` and it installed it just version 2.7. I also tried to use easy_install somehow but it claims it's already installed in p2.7. How can I get it running on python3??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found the solution. So to install psutil for python3 you should:

1. Download psutil sources from http://code.google.com/p/psutil/downloads/list
2. Extract tar file in some tmp directory
3. Open terminal and go to this directory
4. Type `sudo apt-get install python3-dev`
5. Type `python3 setup.py install`

I believe that this approach would work fine also for other libraries when you have multiple pythons on the system. Hope someone will save some time :)